# Incref of params to PyEval_EvalCode depending on script

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython

In the following *MCVE* two different scripts get executed. Both don't do anything special, the first one has an empty function, the second script does literally nothing. But depending on the script [PyEval_EvalCode](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyEval_EvalCode) increfs the passed global/local dictionary or not. The documentation doesn't say anything. But depending on the script I have a dangling dictionary after it got executed. When do I have to decref them afterwards or when not? Or what am I missing here? The following C snippet outputs the refcount of the passed dictionaries.

I tried this on Windows with the standard Python-2.7 interpreter.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "C:\\Python27\\libs\\python27.lib")
#include "C:\\Python27\\include\\Python.h"

static int execute(const char* script)
{
    PyObject* globals = PyDict_New();
    PyDict_SetItemString(globals, "__builtins__", PyEval_GetBuiltins());

    PyObject* code = Py_CompileString(script, "test", Py_file_input);
    if (!code)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        return 0;
    }

    PyObject* result = PyEval_EvalCode((PyCodeObject*)code, globals, nullptr);
    Py_DECREF(code);

    if (!result)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        return 0;
    }

    Py_DECREF(result);
    printf("Refcount of globals: %zd\n", globals->ob_refcnt);
    Py_DECREF(globals); // missing decref spotted by user2357112

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    const char* script = nullptr;

    Py_Initialize();

    // First script contains a function
    script = 
        "def main():\n" \
        "    pass\n" \
        "main()\n";
    execute(script);

    // second script does nothing
    script = "12345";
    execute(script);

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tracing everything down I realized there is a circular reference. The function gets a reference to the globals dictionary, and the dictionary keeps the function alive. Calling the garbage collector right after the script got executed fixes the problem and the circular reference gets resolved.

```
execute(script);
PyGC_Collect();
```

**P.S.** Credit goes also to user2357112 who spotted a missing *decref* in my MCVE.

Answer (score 2):

The extra reference is the function's own reference to its global variable dict. This reference is not your concern, and you do not need to decref that reference.

You only need to perform decrefs to account for clearing references you own.

Comment: Thanks, great confirmation, I just saw the assignment in PyFunction_New(). But when do they get dereferenced? My problem, all objects in the global scope are still alive, although the scope reached the end of it's lifetime.

Comment: @HelloWorld: Python doesn't promise it'll happen at any particular time. For this example, it'll probably happen during `Py_Finalize`.

Comment: I just tried it out with a data breakpoint, even in Py_Finalize the reference count doesn't get touched anymore

Comment: @HelloWorld: You never decref'd your *own* reference to the dict!

Comment: Thanks for spotting, deleted it by accident while creating the MCVE